# Update query won't work

Tags: php

hello im trying to update my DB but doesn't seem to work still kinda new to php so don't really know if the query i made is correct... but i dont get any errors and i think ive given the correct variables

```
<?php
          $username = "root";
          $password = null;
          $host = "localhost";
          $dbname = "newspaper_system";
          $conn = new mysqli($host,$username,$password ,$dbname);
        if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
        mysqli_connect("localhost","root", $password  ) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        mysqli_select_db($conn,"newspaper_system") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    if(!$conn){
        die("cant connect db". mysql_error());
    }
    if(isset($_POST['update'])){

        $updatesql = "UPDATE newspaper_system SET Newspaper='$_POST[Newspaper]', Price='$_POST[Price]', Pricepersquare='$_POST[Pricepersquare]' WHERE News_ID='$_POST[hidden]'";
        $conn->query($updatesql);
        print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
        print 'alert("UPDATE successful")';
        print '</script>';  
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM newspaper_library") or die(mysql_error($conn));
    echo "<center><table border=1>
    <tr>
    <td><label>News ID</td>
    <td><label>Newspaper</td>
    <td><label>Price</td>
    <td><label>Pricepersquare</td>

    </tr>";
    while($record= mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<form action=Update.php method=post>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td> <label>". $record['News_ID'] . " </td>";
        echo "<td>". "<input type=text name=Newspaper  value =\"" . $record['Newspaper']. "\"> </td>";
            echo "<td>". "<input type=text name=Price value=\"" . $record['Price']. "\"> </td>";
        echo "<td>". "<input type=text name=Pricepersquare value=\"" . $record['Pricepersquare']. "\"> </td>";
        echo "<td>". "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $record['News_ID']. " </td>";
        echo "<td>". "<input type=submit name=update value=update " . " </td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</form>";     


    }
    echo "</table>";

    $conn->

        close();    

        ?

    >
```

Comment: Have you checked the DB and there is no update? No error messages? Is your display_errors correctly set at php.ini?

Comment: yes i checked in both my phpmyadmin and the display table i made .. yeah it is correctly set

Comment: You are selecting from `newspaper_library` -> `SELECT * FROM newspaper_library`, but updating `newspaper_system` -> `UPDATE newspaper_system`. Is this intended/correct?

Comment: Why are you doing both `$conn = new mysqli(...)` and `mysqli_connect(...)`?

Comment: Sean Thank you ^_^ its working fine now my error was i was updating my DB not the table :) .. it;s updating fine now

Comment: @JoshuaTriumfanteDeVeraIII You should still change your typos from `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*`, even though no errors are caused as it didn't execute `die()`, more info at my answer

Comment: @luweiqi yeah :) im changing it at this moment thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you cannot mix `mysql_*` functions with `mysqli_*` functions:

```
if(!$conn){
    //should be 'die("cant connect db". mysqli_error($conn));'
   die("cant connect db". mysql_error());
}
```

Here also:

```
// should be 'or die(mysqli_error($conn))'
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM newspaper_library") or die(mysql_error($conn));
```

---

Secondly, your closing tags is wrong:

```
        ?

    >
```

It should be `?>`.

---

Thirdly, your `UPDATE` query is vulnerable to potential SQL Injection *(Thanks @sean for pointing out)*:

```
$updatesql = "UPDATE newspaper_system SET Newspaper='$_POST[Newspaper]', Price='$_POST[Price]', Pricepersquare='$_POST[Pricepersquare]' WHERE News_ID='$_POST[hidden]'";
```

It's a better way to assign it to a variable first:

```
$newspaper = $_POST['Newspaper'];
$price = $_POST['Price'];
$pricepersquare = $_POST['Pricepersquare'];
$news_id = $_POST['hidden'];

$updatesql = "UPDATE newspaper_system SET Newspaper='$newspaper', Price='$price', Pricepersquare='$pricepersquare' WHERE News_ID='$news_id'";
```

---

**Note:**

You are selecting from `newspaper_library`:

```
SELECT * FROM newspaper_library
```

But updating `newspaper_system`:

```
UPDATE newspaper_system
```

Not sure if it's intended.

Comment: as to your `Thirdly`, `'$_POST[Newspaper]'` is valid php syntax inside double quotes (although very bad idea due to sql injection or possible quote issues). If they quote the key, then they would use curly brackets -> `'{$_POST['Newspaper']}'`

Comment: ohh tnx ill try to fix up the proper form writing up php codes